# Checking for JavaScript null values

Tags: javascript, web-applications, yui, yahoo

I'm using the Yahoo User Interface API.  If I have the following:

```
var field = yuiDom.get('dobfield');
```

Is it necessary to check for something like:

```
if (field == null)
```

I'm a .NET developer, and whenever I try to get a reference to a control on my web page then I always check for null values. I checked the YUI examples, and references to controls are used extensively, but no where do I see if they check to see if there was a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might see this:

```
if(field)
```

or

```
if(!field)
```

Essentially these mean if is null, and if is not null. However, they are equivalent to

```
if (field == null)
```

and

```
if (field != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In YUI 2 you could do this:

```
var lang = YAHOO.util.Lang;    
var ctl = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("dobfield");

if (lang.isNull(ctl)) {
   alert("Control is null");
} else { 
   alert("found control");
}
```

[YAHOO.util.Lang](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yahoo/#lang) is part of the global YAHOO object and it has a bunch of useful cross-browser functions, such as isNull.  Since you are using YAHOO.util.Dom, you have Lang by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing controls that you created and know that will be there, I don't see it as necessary to check for null.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript `null` values are rarely used, and you won't have a `null` value unless you explicitly define it, instead there's `undefined` value for non-referenced object, and as Corey Sunwold said, you may see this:

```
if(obj) {
    alert(true); // obj could be (object, not empty string, not null, a not zero number)
} else {
    alert(false); // obj could be (undefined, null, '', 0)
}
```

the previous method does not work with empty objects and empty arrays, you may use jquery [isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) method instead for this case.

Comment: Your if isn't similiar to Corey's if. Isn't your first if supposed to check for undefined/null?  Don't you have it the other way around?

Comment: yes it will check for undefined, null, zero, and empty strings